# Not able to map keys [ ] for Ctrl-e abd Ctrl-y in VIM

Tags: vim

I am new to the VIM editor and I wanted to bind `[ ]` to `Ctrl-e` and `Ctrl-Y` respectively.

But this is not working.

I have tried:

```
nnoremap [ <C-e>                                                                                                                                                                                                
nnoremap ] <C-y>
```

However below mapping is working fine for me.

```
nnoremap ; <C-e>                                                                                                                                                                                                
nnoremap ' <C-y>


vim --version
```

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug  9 2019 03:17:15)

Comment: For me, this all works. The bracket mappings just take a second to respond, because they have to be distinguished from multi-key commands that begin with a bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly because you have other mappings that *start* with `[` or `]`, and Vim is waiting for you to complete them. (`:help map-ambiguous`, `:help map-typing`, `:help :map-nowait`, `:help timeout`, `:help timeoutlen`).

Check your mappings: `:verbose map [`, `:verbose map ]`